# how to add password to mod_jk status page

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, authentication, mod-jk

I'm using apache2 and mod_jk for balancing requests throw servers. my problem is that everybody can access to status page of mod_jk .
is there any way to add authentication for that? (I can't use read_only mode because i have to edit balancer specification from that page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a  directive before the mod_jk stuff to do the authentication. For example:

```
<Location "/status">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
    Require user admin
  </Location>
```